# Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction()

Tags: error, model, adminform, save

I have created a custom module "adminform" with some custom fields when i try to save my form data it gives the error

> "Call to a member function beginTransaction()"

I have the following form fields:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save'),
        'method' => 'post',
        ));

    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $helper = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany');
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array('legend' => $helper->__('Select Social Icons'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'));

    $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'facebook',
        'label' => $helper->__('Facebook'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('google', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'google',
        'label' => $helper->__('Google'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('twitter', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'twitter',
        'label' => $helper->__('Twitter'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('linkedin', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'linkedin',
        'label' => $helper->__('Linkedin'),
        ));
    $fieldset->addField('yelp', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'yelp',
        'label' => $helper->__('Yelp'),
        ));


    if (Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->getData());
    }

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

**And following is my Saveaction method in controller:**

```
 public function saveAction()
    {

    //$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
if ( $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams() ) {

    $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
    $model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->setData($data);
    //$model = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review');
    print_r($model->getData());

        try {
        $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
        echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
        } catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();   
        }

    return;
}
```

**Also I have define the model in my configuration file like :**

```
<models>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource</resourceModel>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <review>
                    <table>optfirst_reviewmycompany</table>
                </review>
            </entities>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
    </models>
```

But still no luck with data save to database is there any wrong thing i am doing please check the code and try to find the mistake that where i am doing wrong..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your model should look like this.

```
<models>
  <reviewmycompany>
    <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model</class>
    <resourceModel>reviewmycompany_resource</resourceModel>
  </reviewmycompany>
  <reviewmycompany_resource>
    <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resource</class>
    <entities>        
        <review>
            <table>optfirst_reviewmycompany</table>
        </review>
    </entities>
  </reviewmycompany_resource>
</models>
```